# List only numerical directory names in linux

Tags: linux, list, directory, numeric

How to list only numerical directory names in Linux.
Only directories, that has only numeric characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to do it.

1.You can List just dirs and then remove . and / from the names and then Grep just numerical ones:

```
ls -d ./*/ | sed 's/\.\///g' | sed 's/\///g' | grep -E '^[0-9]+$'
```

2.By "ls" & "grep" & then "awk". Just list with details, Grep dirs and then Print 9th column:

```
ls -llh | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'
```

Good luck In Arbaeen.

Comment: Tnx, the answer is: ls -d +([0-9])/ | sed 's/\///g'

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can benefit from extended globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -d +([0-9])/
```

Where

> ```
> +(pattern-list)
> ```
>
> Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns

The `/` at the end limits the list to directories, and `-d` prevents `ls` from listing their contents.

Comment: Your answer need another piping, since it returns the names with slash. So, please add: | sed 's/\///g'

Comment: @MohsenAbasi: Depends on what you want to do with them which isn't clear in the OP.